# Hide a keyboard in Android Delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, keyboard

I really need this! When I enter into a edit, the keyboard shows automaticly .. but when I touch out of the edit, the keyboard don't hide! I looking for a answer, but I can't do it!
Please, can someone help me?!

Comment: Maybe you can find some hints in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182353/how-to-detect-virtual-keyboard-events-in-android-with-delphi

Comment: if you use Tedit on android, i suggest you to use an native android edit. i often founded the firemonkey Tedit a little buggy (like with the keyboard, that is connected to a "virtual proxy textfield" because the Tedit is not a java component it's 100% drawed by delphi). You can try the compiled demo here: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALFmxControls/Android/Release/ALFmxControls/bin/ALFmxControls.apk ) and the source code here: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/

Answer (score 5):

FireMonkey has special service for managing Virtual Keyboard. It is IFMXVirtualKeyboardService ([Embarcadero Docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.VirtualKeyboard.IFMXVirtualKeyboardService)). Which allows you to show and hide the keyboard. 
To hide the keyboard try the following code:

```
uses
  FMX.Platform, FMX.VirtualKeyboard;

procedure TForm5.ButtonHideKeybordClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  KeyboardService: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, IInterface(KeyboardService)) then
    KeyboardService.HideVirtualKeyboard;
end;
```

To show keyboard

```
procedure TForm5.ButtonShowKeyboardClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  KeyboardService: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, IInterface(KeyboardService)) then
    KeyboardService.ShowVirtualKeyboard(Edit1);
end;
```